# Bitcoin curl no reply

Tags: bitcoind, client, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

Hi I have made a curl to my server but get no reply . What am a missing

```
 rpcuser=rpcusername
 rpcpassword=rpcpassword
 rpcauth=rpcusername:generatedkey
 daemon=1
 server=1
 rpcport=8332
 rpcbind=0.0.0.0:8332
 rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
 listen=1
 rpcconnect=0.0.0.0
 prune=10000
```

Whats strange is that it worked on another server. Why am I bot getting any reply. Bitcoin cli commands all work well . I get no reply not even the usual "empty reply"

---

Ive used this

```
curl --digest -u rpcusername:rpcpassword -X POST \
  127.0.0.1:8332/json_rpc \ 
  -d {\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":\"0\",\"method\":\"getwalletinfo\"}" \
  -H 'Content-Type:application/json'
```

also swapped it with the IP, still no reply.

Comment: Why are you binding to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Im testing, will that cause an issue ?

Comment: What is the curl command that you are using?

Comment: Ive used this curl --digest -u rpcusername:rpcpassword -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8332/json_rpc -d "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":\"0\",\"method\":\"getwalletinfo\"}" -H 'Content-Type:application/json' also swapped it with the Ip still no reply.

Comment: Are you sure the chain is fully synced?  Also add `curl -v` the `-v flag is verbose and will help you a bit more when debugging.  Not an empty reply means that your `bitcoind` responded on the RPC port just didn't do anything because it was called incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the RPC interface incorrectly.  Your curl -

```
$ curl --digest -u rpcusername:rpcpassword -X POST \ 
    127.0.0.1:8332/json_rpc \
    -d "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":\"0\",\"method\":\"getwalletinfo\"}" \
    -H 'Content-Type:application/json'
```

has an incorrect path `127.0.0.1:8332/json_rpc` you are posting to.  You should create your curl request with the following path - `127.0.0.1:8332/`.

Working example, printing verbosely with `-v`

```
$ curl -v --digest -u rpcusername:rpcpassword -X POST \
    127.0.0.1:8332/ \
    -d "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":\"0\",\"method\":\"getwalletinfo\"}" \
    -H 'Content-Type:application/json'
```

Comment: No luck Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.

Comment: Yeah was just updating the call you posted in the comment section with the approriate URL.

Answer (score 0):

> @GildedHonour Authentication is not optional. Configuring it yourself is optional, but bitcoind never accepts RPC connections without explicitly or implicitly configured username/password.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/10218

Edit your `bitcoind.conf`, add RPC auth and it'll work.